Keycloak TestContainer doesn't want to run in Development Time (Spring Boot)
I want to prepare a SpringBoot configuration in Test directory which runs with test containers. In my particular case, the container is Keycloak.
I followed the official documentation, but it doesn't work.
The container is not running. Spring doesn't hit the method: keycloakContainer and then it fails due to unexisting Keycloak URL.
package net.beans.java.example.microservice.simple;

import dasniko.testcontainers.keycloak.KeycloakContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartScope;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;

import static net.beans.java.example.microservice.simple.SimpleMicroserviceResourceBaseTest.CLENT_ID;
import static net.beans.java.example.microservice.simple.SimpleMicroserviceResourceBaseTest.CLIENT_SECRET;

@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class TestSimpleMicroserviceApplication {

    @Bean
    @RestartScope
    public KeycloakContainer keycloakContainer(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        KeycloakContainer keycloak = new KeycloakContainer("quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2")
                .withEnv("DB_VENDOR", "h2")
                .withAdminUsername("admin")
                .withAdminPassword("admin")
                .withContextPath("/auth")
                .withRealmImportFile("/simple-application-realm.json");

        registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri", () -> keycloak.getAuthServerUrl() + "/realms/simple-application-realm");
        registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri", () -> keycloak.getAuthServerUrl() + "/realms/simple-application-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token");
        registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id", () -> CLENT_ID);
        registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret", () -> CLIENT_SECRET);
        return keycloak;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.from(SimpleMicroserviceApplication::main).with(TestSimpleMicroserviceApplication.class).run(args);
    }

}

The exception which I get is as follows:
Factory method 'jwtDecoder' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8081/realms/simple-application-realm"

It means, SpringBoot took spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri property from application.properties.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.
